# Redirecting to subpage with id

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've had two routes:

```
<Route path="/client/:id/members" component={Members} />
<Route path="/client/:id/members/:mid" component={MemberProfile} />
```

why when I'm trigger:

```
window.location.href = `/client/${id}/members/${mid}`;
```

then my url is changed to correct form like in the route path but not redirect me to `MemberProfile` component?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

as

```
<Route path="/client/:id/members" component={Members} />
```

declared before

```
<Route path="/client/:id/members/:mid" component={MemberProfile} />
```

and

```
/client/${id}/members/${mid}
```

fit

```
"/client/:id/members"
```

`Members` component will still be rendered.

Consider one of the following:

1. decleare `MemberProfile` before `Members`
2. change `MembersProfile` route to `/client/:id/member/:mid` for example
3. use `exact` `Route` property

Answer (score 2):

Given:

> ```
> <Route path="/client/:id/members" component={Members} />
> <Route path="/client/:id/members/:mid" component={MemberProfile} />
> ```

It seems like you are rendering these routes into a `Switch` component. Remember that the `Switch` component renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. This means that route path order and specificity matters.

Order your routes by decreasing specificity. `"/client/:id/members/:mid"` is more specific than `"/client/:id/members"` and should render higher in the `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route path="/client/:id/members/:mid" component={MemberProfile} />
  <Route path="/client/:id/members" component={Members} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

### Additional note

You may want to avoid using `window.location.href` to redirect as this reloads the entire page, and thus, your app. Use a `Redirect` component to render a declarative navigation, or use `` history.replace(`/client/${id}/members/${mid}`); `` to issue an imperative redirect.